# Populating spinner from Firebase data

Tags: android, json, firebase, android-spinner, firebase-realtime-database

I want to populate a secound spinner based on the choice of the first spinner. as you can see in my firebase Json there elements set under each workout that have values true or false. If a element is true under a workout I want to show that element name in the second spinner.Example, if user chooses Heavy Chest and Arms in the first spinner then both Bench press and Incline Dumbbell Press should populate the second spinner. I get some response with my current code but don´t get the keys value out right now.

Json file:

```js
{
  "elements" : {
    "element_id_0" : {
      "description" : "While laying flat on your back, arms at 90 degrees etc",
      "name" : "Bench press"
    },
    "element_id_1" : {
      "description" : "Incline the backboard 30 degrees and etc etc",
      "name" : "Incline Dumbbell Press"
    }
  },
  "workouts" : {
    "workout_id_0" : {
      "category" : "Heavy Chest and Arms",
      "elements" : {
        "element_id_0" : "true",
        "element_id_1" : "true"
      }
    },
    "workout_id_1" : {
      "category" : "Light Back and Shoulders",
      "elements" : {
        "element_id_0" : "true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Some of my code:

```java
 FirebaseSpinnerRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
             String category=postSnapshot.child("category").getValue().toString();
             if(category.equals(sp1)) {
                 Object j =postSnapshot.child("elements").getValue();
             }
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
Object j =postSnapshot.child("elements").getValue();
```

Use

```
Elements_post = postSnapshot.child("elements").getValue(Elements_.class);
```

You can get your values by calling Getters in the below class

```
public class Elements_ {
private ElementId0 elementId0;
private ElementId1 elementId1;
    public Elements_ (){
// must have empty construct to bind the data
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The elementId0
*/
public ElementId0 getElementId0() {
return elementId0;
}



/**
* 
* @return
* The elementId1
*/
public ElementId1 getElementId1() {
return elementId1;
}

public class ElementId0 {

private String description;
private String name;

/**
* 
* @return
* The description
*/
public String getDescription() {
return description;
}


/**
* 
* @return
* The name
*/
public String getName() {
return name;
}
}

public class ElementId1 {

private String description;
private String name;

/**
* 
* @return
* The description
*/
public String getDescription() {
return description;
}



/**
* 
* @return
* The name
*/
public String getName() {
return name;
}


}

}
```

have a look [Get data from firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html)

Comment: That´s a nice beginning but I want to check if that element is true under workouts and if it is i want to get i from the elements.